# a null progressbar is created?

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar

When I run the code below it prints "null" in the log file... What is the problem with it?

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
if (progressBar == null) {
    Log.d("tag", "null");
}
```

and the xml call is:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="37dp"
    android:layout_y="343dp" />
```

Comment: Try running Project > Clean from Eclipse, or `ant clean` from the command line, then try running your app again.

Comment: Did you call setContentView before?

Comment: Thanks Binyamin, that solved it, can you put your comment as an answer so that I accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `layout` with your `ProgressBar` in it has to have been inflated first, and you may need to use `View.findViewById()` instead of `Activity.findViewById()`.  I actually had this problem this morning, and my fix is here:

```
    LayoutInflater infl = uI.getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup rootGroup = (ViewGroup) uI.findViewById(R.id.voltoast_root);
    View root = infl.inflate(R.layout.volumetoast, rootGroup);
    toast.setView(root);
    pB = (ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.progress);
```

I am calling `findViewById()` on the `root` instead of on my `Activity`, and `root` has the inflated view which included a `LinearLayout` in which `ProgressBar` was one element.

Answer (score 0):

change the style to this:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
```